# netstat -a command listing info like :::30179, :::www

Tags: ipv6, upnp

The `netstat -a` command lists info like this:

```
tcp        0      0 :::30179                :::*           LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::www                  :::*           LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::10001                :::*           LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::telnet               :::*           LISTEN
```

What does it mean? I try to find out, but i couldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Those sockets are listening on the IPv6 unspecified address, which is `::`. This is short for `0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000` (multiple block of 0 may be compressed into `::`, see [RFC 5952](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5952)). This is similar to the IPv4 unspecified address `0.0.0.0`. It means that the service is listening on all addresses of the host.

Usually listening on an IPv6 socket means that the socket only accepts incoming connections from IPv6 clients, and the software would need to open a second socket to listen for IPv4 clients.

There is one special case however: listening on the IPv6 unspecified address and having the `IPV6_V6ONLY` flag set to 0 (false). On many systems, including Linux, this is the default. In that case the socket will accept both IPv4 and IPv6 clients on a single socket. This feature makes it easier for software developers to support IPv6: they can write software that just listens for both protocols using a single socket.

The downside of this is that it is not easy to see which sockets listen on both protocols and which sockets only listen on IPv6. It is also confusing that `:` is used in the IPv6 address and also as the separator between the address and the port. That way you get the confusing `:::` bit.

BSD based systems tend to show the same information in a different way. There your example would be displayed as e.g.:

```
tcp46      0      0  *.30179              *.*               LISTEN
tcp46      0      0  *.www                *.*               LISTEN
tcp46      0      0  *.10001              *.*               LISTEN
tcp46      0      0  *.telnet             *.*               LISTEN
```

A server that uses two separate sockets for IPv4 and IPv6 shows up as:

```
tcp4       0      0  *.ssh                *.*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0  *.ssh                *.*               LISTEN
```

and

```
udp4       0      0  *.ntp                *.*
udp6       0      0  *.ntp                *.*
```

I personally like that it explicitly shows which protocols are being listened on (i.e. `tcp4`/`tcp6`/`tcp46`) and using the `*` character for the unspecified address.

I just noticed that recent Ubuntu versions use this notation:

```
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                 *:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh              [::]:*            LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:https            [::]:*            LISTEN
```

Which is already a lot clearer. Unfortunately it doesn't show the difference between a socket that listens only on IPv6 (like the `ssh` socket) and a socket that listens on both IPv4 and IPv6 (like the `https` socket).